# Uncertain_conversion_exception in Nef polyhedra

Tags: cgal

I an using Nef Polyhedra for some 3D boolean operation. I first convert a bunch polyhedron_3 meshes into Nef_polyhedron_3 meshes and then perform the boolean operation. However, almost any manipulation of the Nef polyhedra results in a bunch of Uncertain_conversion_exception. I tried running CGAL with CGAL_PROFILE profile. This told me that the I get this exception on two different types. These are

```
GCAL::Uncertain<enum CGAL::Sign>
CGAL::Uncertain<bool>
```

Especially the second is thrown a lot. They are throw both when converting meshes into Nef polyhedra and during the boolean operations them selves. The call that that throws the exception is made in `Filtered_predicate`. The exceptions are being handled here and the boolean operation returns the expected result. However, the exceptions seems to slow down the operations quite a bit.

I am experiencing this with CGAL 4.7 on windows using visual studio 2015.I have the following symbols defined for the preprocessor

```
WIN32;
_WINDOWS;
_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;
_SCL_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE;
_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;
_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;
_DEBUG;CGAL_USE_MPFR;
CGAL_USE_GMP;
BOOST_ALL_DYN_LINK;
CMAKE_INTDIR="Debug";
CGAL_EXPORTS;
```

CGAL is built with the flags: `/GR`, `/EHsc`, `fp:strict`,  `fp:except-`, `/wd4503` and `/bigobj`.

Additionally the project that includes CGAL is build with the flags: `/GS`  `/Zc:wchar_t` `/Zc:inline` `/fp:precise` `/Zc:forScope` `/clr` `/MDd` `/EHa`

I left out a bunch flags that didn't seem relevant like include flags.

Is this expected behavior or can i do something to avoid it?

Comment: Can you provided some additional (Compiler? platform? CXX_FLAGS?).

Comment: I added the information in the question.

Comment: Well, that's how Filtered_predicate works. First try to evaluate the predicate with interval arithmetic. If that fails (something is degenerate or close to degenerate), more precision is needed, the interval code throws an exception and Filtered_predicate tries again with infinite precision (slow). If you want more info, you could try to identify which predicate fails this way on which configuration of points, to see if calling the predicate is avoidable in the first place.

Comment: It happens for very simple meshes. Currently I am experiencing it with simple 5 point meshes, forming a dual tetrahedron with these points: `{0, 0, -1.5, 0, 1.5, 0, 1.3, -0.7, 0, -1.3, -0.7, 0, 0, 0, 1.5}`. It's happens both during the construction of the meshes and when performing a union of the meshes. If i change the points to integers, the exceptions disappear. I can't really avoid certain configurations of points as it has to be a general solution.